# C++ using a function within a function gives unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, function

Trying to compile the code below in Visual Studio 2010 gives me two errors about an unresolved external symbol. I'm pretty sure the issue is because I am using a function within a function but I don't know specifically what I am doing incorrectly. The code looks ok to me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class fraction
{
  public:
    int gcd(int, int);
    void simplifyfraction();
  private:
    int integral, numerator, denominator;
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}

int gcd(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    if (denominator > numerator)
       return gcd(denominator, numerator);
    if (numerator == denominator)
       return numerator;
    if (numerator%denominator == 0)
       return denominator;
    return gcd(numerator, numerator-denominator);
}


void fraction::simplifyfraction()
{
    int mygcd;
    mygcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
    numerator = numerator/mygcd;
    denominator = denominator/mygcd;
}
```

Comment: it might be helpful to include the error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of `gcd()` is not qualified with the class name and is treated as a free standing function, a *different* function from the member function `gcd()` declared in the `fraction` class.

As `gcd()` is invoked from `fraction::simplifyfraction()` the compiler searches for a function named `gcd()` and the first it finds is declared in the same scope as `simplifyfraction()`, namely `fraction::gcd()` which has no definition (it does not find the fully defined freestanding `gcd()` function). The linker subsequently complains that it has an unresolved symbol.

To correct change to:

```
int fraction::gcd(int numerator, int denominator)
{
}
```

---

Just to note this could also have been fixed by not having `gcd()` as a member function (it does not access any member variables of `fraction`, all variables are passed as arguments) or the invocation of `gcd()` in `fraction::simplifyfraction()` could be changed to:

```
mygcd = ::gcd(numerator, denominator);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of gcd does not declare itself to be a member function of fraction.

You need to write:

```
int fraction::gcd(int numerator, int denominator)
```